# Define Macros depending on argument

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to draw some linear Systems with tikz. The problem is the orientation of the Systems. Some have

- input on left - output on right
- input on right - output on left
- input above - output below
- input below - output above

So to handle all the variations with a single \command, i'd like to use the arguments

- ud (up down)
- du (down up)
- lr (left right)
- rl (right left)

So what I need is a switch in Latex to define the Orientationparameter.

pseudocode:

```
\drawSYS{Text}{lr}

Command: drawSYS
 \switch #2
  \case 'lr'
   \def\ORIENTA left
   \def\ORIENTB right
  \case 'rl'
   \def\ORIENTA right
   \def\ORIENTB left
   ....
 \endswitch
 \node[anchor=\ORIENTA,\ORIENTB=1cm] () {foobar};
```

Is this even possible in Tex?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking exactly. Maybe give an example of what you'd like the macro to look like and what it should expand to depending on its arguments.

Comment: Naturally it is possible. You only need to look at the documentation of tikz and the use of words like "left" "right" "north" "above" .... Or take the optional arguments [t], [b] of tabular.

Comment: I'd like to have a single macro which has a single argument to define weather it is left(anchor right) or right(anchor left) (+ the combinations with up/down)

Comment: I'm not sure that I completely understand, but it seems as though what you'd like is to specify a single option which did, say, `anchor=east,rotate=90`.  Or `anchor=east,xscale=-1`.  That's easy enough to do using _styles_.  Does that sound like what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a general "cases" type command that is also usefull ouside the `tikz` community ;-). It returns an `\ifcase <pos>` in a list

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\@testlist{}
\newcommand*\@invalue{}
\newcommand*\@choiceval{}
\newcounter{itemcount}
\newcommand*\ifchoice[2]{%
    \edef\@testlist{\zap@space#1 \@empty}%
    \edef\@invalue{\zap@space#2 \@empty}%
    \def\@choiceval{99}%
    \setcounter{itemcount}{-1}%
    \@for\@testitem:=\@testlist\do{%
        \stepcounter{itemcount}%
        \ifx\@invalue\@testitem\relax
            \edef\@choiceval{\the\c@itemcount}%
        \fi}%
        \ifcase\@choiceval}

\newcommand*\drawSYS[2]{%
    \ifchoice{ud, du, lr, rl}{#2}%
       %-------------------- 0  = ud
        \def\ORIENTA{Up}%
        \def\ORIENTB{Down}%
    \or%-------------------- 1  = du
        \def\ORIENTA{Down}%
        \def\ORIENTB{Up}%
    \or%-------------------- 2  = lr
        \def\ORIENTA{Left}%
        \def\ORIENTB{Right}%
    \or%-------------------- 3  = rl
        \def\ORIENTA{Right}%
        \def\ORIENTB{Left}%
    \else%------------------ 99 = default
        \def\ORIENTA{Left}%
        \def\ORIENTB{Right}%
    \fi
    (#1)(#2)[\ORIENTA][\ORIENTB]}%--- Test output

\makeatother
\begin{document}
   \drawSYS{xxx}{ rl }
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a very good generalized solution.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was searching for. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `pgfkeys` `.is choice` option. It looks like you don't actually want to execute pieces of code depending on the choice, but merely set styles, which makes this approach the obvious choice. Note that you could also execute code pieces by using `\pgfkeys{/tikz/orientation/lr/.code=<code>}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{orientation/.is choice,
    orientation/lr/.style={anchor=left,right=1cm},
    orientation/rl/.style={anchor=right,left=1cm}
}

\newcommand{\drawSYS}[2]{
    \node [orientation=#1] {#2};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style=draw]
\draw [fill=red] (0,0) circle [radius=3pt];
\drawSYS{lr}{X}
\drawSYS{rl}{Y}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: tikz .is choice]

Comment: Oh. This solution is nice. Didn't think of that. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [`xparse`](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/doc/latex/xpackages/xparse.pdf) package has a lot of argument dependent macro-defining capabilities. I don't know if it supports string comparison though.